# PHP: Search for a string in XML

Tags: php, xml

I try the search code below but it is only showing the first child node. Is something missing from my code?

----catalog.xml----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog>
    <Category>
        <Name>CAT1</Name>
        <Location>
            <Room>Alpha</Room>
        </Location>
        <Location>
            <Room>Bravo</Room>
        </Location>  
        <Location>
            <Room>Charlie</Room>
        </Location>  
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <Name>CAT2</Name>
        <Location>
            <Room>Delta</Room>
        </Location>  
        <Location>
            <Room>Eagle</Room>
        </Location>  
        <Location>
            <Room>Falcon</Room>
        </Location>  
    </Category>
</Catalog>
```

----arr0.php----

```
<?php
$catalog = simplexml_load_file("catalog.xml");
$category = $catalog->Category;

foreach($category->Name as $name)
{
    $menu = (string)$name;
    $i = 0;
    if ($menu == "CAT1" )
{
        echo $category->Location->Room[$i];
        $i++;       
}
else 
{
        echo "No result";
}
}
?>
```

---------Output----------

Alpha

---

Bravo and Charlie is missing from display.  Need someone advise where am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
<?php
$catalog = simplexml_load_file("catalog.xml");
$category = $catalog->Category;
$found = false;
foreach($category as $c)
{
    $menu = (string) ($c->Name);
    if ($menu == "CAT1" )
    {
        foreach ($c->Location as $loc)
        {
            echo $loc->Room;
        }
        $found = true; break;
    }
}
if (!$found)
{
    echo "No result";
}
?>
```

Remove the `break;` statement if you can have more than one Category with the searched Name element.

Comment: Hi guido, it still shows Alpha only.  What happen to the $i?   See my result:   
Alpha
Check print_r SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Alpha )
Check var_dump object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(5) "Alpha" } Bravo
Check print_r SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Bravo )
Check var_dump object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(5) "Bravo" } Charlie
Check print_r SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Charlie )
Check var_dump object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(7) "Charlie" } No result

Comment: I tested it locally now, it outputs "AlphaBravoCharlie"

Comment: Hi Guido, tested result:   AlphaBravoCharlieNo result //The No result also appear, means the If Else statement failed.

Comment: "AlphaBravoCharlie" is the result for CAT1, while "No result" is the result for CAT2 (or any other category name). Isn't that what you want?

Comment: ok I think I understand what is your actual desired result now, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try to revise your code to:

```
echo $category->Location[$i]->Room;
```

Comment: Tried but still the same.  I created a print_r and var_dump as follows:                          Alpha
Check print_rSimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Alpha )
Check var_dumpobject(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(5) "Alpha" }